# Transactionally update a set of files in s3

Tags: data, aws

I have a bucket with several csv files at differing paths. The problem is that I want to update these csv files transactionally. The s3 bucket should represent the "latest" consistent set of data, and if any update to one of the s3 paths fails, then no update should happen. My s3 bucket for example would look like this

```
s3://bucketname/path/to/file1.csv
s3://bucketname/other/file2.csv
s3://bucketname/much/longer/path/to/file3.csv
...
```

I need to design a workflow to update these CSVs at these highly specific paths transactionally. A user would query for a CSV at a specific path or query for multiple CSVs at different specific paths. That's why the data refresh must be consistent.

Let's pretend there are 100 CSVs. The only acceptable states are:

- all the CSVs are stale
- all the CSVs are new
- some of the CSVs are new, and the other CSVs are missing.

We **CANNOT** have a situation where some CSVs are new and accessible, but older CSVs are still accessible. This would lead to surfacing new and old data together, which is bad. For example, if a user queries for the following 2 paths:

```
s3://bucketname/path/to/file1.csv
s3://bucketname/much/longer/path/to/file3.csv
```

and through my workflow, a new CSV was written to `s3://bucketname/path/to/new_file1.csv` but the CSV generation for `s3://bucketname/much/longer/path/to/new_file3.csv` failed, then this would result in data from new_file1.csv and file3.csv being shown together. this is bad.

Therefore, I need to make CSVs at a given path "accessible" only when all paths have been updated. If some paths were not updated, then don't show anything for those paths.

I've been playing with several ideas but its difficult and there is a lot of information to keep track of with AWS services.

Idea 1: For each CSV path, keep 2 folders "red" and "blue" for example. A metadata table will keep track of - for each path - whether the latest dataset is in "blue" or is in "red". A user would query this metadata table first for the given path they are interested in, determine whether they should look in "blue" or "red" based on the response, and then access the dataset. When I generate CSVs, I will write to the other folder. So if a given CSV is at path /path/to/file/A/, then I will write a CSV to /path/to/file/B/. I will only update this metadata table if CSV generation for all paths was successful.

This works but it forces the user to query the metadata table first before accessing any dataset. It would be ideal if user could keep just a list of static paths and always know that when they access those paths, all data in those paths is consistent.

Idea 2: Write CSVs first to intermediate S3 bucket. If all CSV generations are successful, then delete everything in output s3 bucket. Once all objects are deleted, copy all paths from intermediate to output s3 bucket.

The con here is that we have to issue a delete + copy s3 api call for each object. That's 2*N calls if we have N datasets. Delete isn't transactional, so if delete fails midway, then we have unnecessarily deleted data but not produced new data.

Idea 3: Write CSVs first to intermediate s3 bucket. Make final portal bucket versioned, so that every object gets a new version. If all CSV generation was successful, issue PutObject requests for each object against final output s3 bucket.

Cons: same as above, except that there is no delete. Also, if there is a failure in any of the PutObject requests, this would surface Old data alongside new data, which is not acceptable.

None of this would be an issue if I could simply replace a group of files at differing paths transactionally in S3.

Comment: Copying files from bucket to bucket reintroduces the possibility of individual failure just like uploading does. S3 simply isn't designed as a transactional database. You probably can't solve this without introducing a guarantee of your own (zipping files together, adding a distinguishing date prefix etc.).

Comment: @KilianFoth does zipping files together still preserve the "directory" structure in s3? wouldn't i need some process to unzip the files before loading into s3?

Comment: Assuming you're not updating too often, the easiest approach I can see would be to have a version number in your CSV headers. Client just needs to check that all versions match when they load a "batch", and retry if not. (A sort of optimistic multi-version concurrency control.)

Comment: @Mat So in that case client would need to check metadata table for what is the correct version right?

Comment: No Metadata table or file needed if the version is in the files themselves. client only needs to check if all the files have the same version (possibly sometimes called a generation number, or something else better that I can't remember right now). (previous incorrect comment deleted)

Comment: Unfortunately they are not loading in batch. They are querying 1 dataset at a time. It would be a big design change on the customer to know in advance what datasets they are interested in and store those somewhere, maybe thats something to think of in the future though.

Comment: S3 has no directories, only paths and keys... There's no container gathering subset of files in FS fashion. The only unit of organization is the bucket.

Comment: On the other hand. Aren't you missing infrastructure? Have you considered implementing other services to do the checkings you don't want users to do? You don't have to give users an S3 URL, you could instead hide it behind a front so you can switch public routes from one S3 bucket to another internally.

Comment: @Laiv I did think of the multi-bucket approach but the users can query datasets that would be across the 2 buckets. The "latest" data they are looking for could either be in bucket A or B. That metadata would need to be tracked. Like I said in the OP keeping metadata for this and checking metadata before accessing a dataset is not a bad idea but I wanted to avoid it. Because of our current design, the user (which is another engineering team) does have to access the metadata themselves. Yes, in the future, we could implement some API front so they don't have to do that

Comment: I was thinking in a DNS or proxy. An element that offers static addresses, routing to S3, so you only have to change the routing when the new files are on S3 and ready.

Comment: Yeah, in the future when I own more of that portion of the architecture I would probably put some API front or proxy that generates the pre-signed url to the correct S3 path for the user.